# RESTFul manage huge resource, representations and projections

Tags: json, api, http, rest, language-agnostic

I need to manage *very big elements* in my *RESTFul* design. 
I'm trying to apply the "divide et impera" method in a way I can spit these elements but It results in smallest element but they are still too large.

- So there are two options that I can use and I'd like to ask you guys your thought on this.

About "representation" I can use different URIs in order to manage them.
Eg.
    /api/resourcex/ for a smallest representation of the resource x
    /api/resourcex_big/ for a big representation of the resource x
    /api/resourcex_full/ for the whole resource x

**ELSE**

I could use a hierarchical approach
    /api/resourcex/
    /api/resourcex/big
    /api/resourcex/full

What do you think is semantically correnct? I choose the first one because I'd like to preserve the hierarchical relation for "sub-elements" of the resource.

Eg. I'd like to use eg. /api/resourcex/ for the **list** of the resourcesx, then use the resourcex_big/{id} as the representation linked from the list of the resource_x as the target detail. Then use resource_full for other kind of representation like the request of full details.

Said that there is a point 2 that is: I need to create something smart in order to do a dynamic projection of that resource. This because the representation is too big for the client and I need to select some datapoints to show that best fit with its needs.
My question here is: which is the best URI format for a projection request? Again, it's better a hierarichical way (like in the e.g. below) or a query string?

```
-- Creation of a projection
**> POST /projection/ HTTP/1.1**
{ resource:”resourcex”, “name”: true, “price”: true } 
**< HTTP/1.1 201 Created**
Location: http://www.sample.org/api/projection/123 (absolute url)
-- Request of a projection
**> GET /resourcex/999/projection/123 HTTP/1.1**
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally would prefer the query-string, because it's the same resource, right?

Write in the docs, that the resource is accessible by the URL `http://example.com/resource/<id>` and it has an optional parameter `size`, that is set to "preview" by default.

```
http://example.com/resource/X   # implies the query-parameter "size=preview"

http://example.com/resource/X?size=preview
http://example.com/resource/X?size=original
```

Other stuff is not rest in my eyes, because the intention is to access one resource using one single URI. In this case, you're accessing the same resource but are asking to get back a modified version of it, in this case, in a different size. And that's something I personally would put in as a query-parameter.

Comment: As far I know we can have different URI point at the same resource as aliases. As far I know I think we can use representations of resources that are the abstraction of that resource we want to expose. Maybe I'm wrong but these are the basic thoughts under the design of those URIs (first section about different representation of a single resource).
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: That said, you could also see a preview-image as a modified version of the original resource, but in this case I would deliver the original resource when calling `http://example.com/resource/<id>`. This would also be the one returned in the location-header, even so you can access the resource in a modified version using a different URI. But I think this depends on how you see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to divide your resources into multiple sub resources.

If there is a **huge** amount of data and you only want some of them, you can design your API to only fetch thoses like this:

```
GET /resources/999/name
GET /resources/999/price
```

Those 2 queries might be much lighter than the full representation of `GET /resources/999`.

One of the **big advantage** of this is that you can **reuse** those URI with other operations, like `POST /resources/999/price` to change the price rather than using `PATCH /resources/999`. It could also simplify your cache clearing strategy so that when you change the price, you only invalidate `/resources/999` and `/resources/999/price` while keeping all `/resources/999/*` entries intact.

In the case your *projections* are **known in advance**, you can create specific media types, e.g.:

```
GET /resources/999
Accept: application/vnd.yourcompany.resourcetype+json
# Receiving full representation of /resources/999

GET /resources/999
Accept: application/vnd.yourcompany.resourcetype.light+json
# Receiving light representation of /resources/999

GET /resources/999
Accept: application/vnd.yourcompany.resourcetype.name_price+json
# Receiving "name" and "price" from /resources/999
```

The advantage of this method is that you can **decrease the number of requests** to fetch many properties without fetching them all.

You can also potentially create an API to create reusable media types ("projections"), but since media types usually defines some contract between the server and the client, it might be a risky approach.